# Python interpreter sequence with a function

Tags: python, function, jupyter, interpreter, definition

**Code**

```
i = 5

def f(arg=i):
    print(arg)
    print(i)

i = 6
f()
```

**Output**

> 5
>
> 6

I just want to understand the sequence or the algorithm it went through. Do it read from the function only its first line (declaration line) and then when the function is called back it read what's inside the function; if this is right, why when an error is done inside the function + after the function (before the function called), the error inside is discovered first? or this has no relation with this? *Please explain*.

**Thank you!**

Comment: Look at `f.__defaults__`.  That's set when the function is created, not when it's run.

Comment: you didn't understand my question btw ):